# Need list of cities/municipalities of Germany along with population density

Tags: data-request, germany, population

I need a list of cities/municipalities/towns/districts of Germany with their associated population density. Is there any free API providing that or a free database?

Comment: Seems like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Germany_by_population has it though there's not a great way to get it other than screen scraping from what I can tell

Answer (score 1):

This [excel table](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiOu7GXhZbsAhWP_aQKHSIxDdAQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.destatis.de%2FDE%2FThemen%2FLaender-Regionen%2FRegionales%2FGemeindeverzeichnis%2FAdministrativ%2F05-staedte.xlsx%3F__blob%3DpublicationFile&usg=AOvVaw3ILEGrnP35OHGg-QmAaTmb) includes a list with more than 2k German cities, their state and municipality. It also includes the surface of each city, its population (females, males, total) and its density (population pro km²). More related stats can be found on the https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Laender-Regionen/Regionales/_inhalt.html.